# How can I line up HAML attributes in vim?

Tags: vim, haml

i'm interested in configuring vim to indent haml attributes. right now they automatically indent to two spaces, but i want them to line up like this:

```
.some-div{ id: something, 
           data: { key: 'value' }, 
           title: 'etc' }
  .the-content
    = whatever
```

this is my current sad state of affairs:

[image]

[image]

i want it to behave more like the way it indents ruby:

[image]

Comment: i've basically gotten what i'm after by modifying tpope's vim-haml: https://github.com/tpope/vim-haml/compare/master...schpet:fix-indentation?expand=1 but it's not a very clean fix. some progress anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use tabular to form vim:

https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular

There's a good vimcast on this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S33w7rcxbOk

Comment: Also, :%s/,\s/,\r/gc

Comment: Also, you can specify a block's for find and replace by selecting in visual mode and typing :'<,'>%s/

Comment: I shortcut that by adding the following to ~/.vimrc  "map <C-n> :%s/"

Comment: thanks for pointing me towards tabular. it looks like it would line things up well after the fact. i am also interested in getting things to line up as i type though, and it doesn't seem like that's what tabular is for. i've updated my question with a few more gifs to help illustrate what i'm after.

Comment: the vimcast I posted shows how to do this when he references the Tim Post gist. Here's a link with the right time https://youtu.be/S33w7rcxbOk?t=263 and here's a link to the gist https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147

Comment: `:Tabularize/\w\+:.*` gets me pretty close to what i'm after. i wasn't able to get it to work in insert mode though. was unable to convert tpope's cucumber example to something that works with haml.

Comment: It seemed tricky. I might look into that a little more next time I'm dealing with a bunch of JSON.